# Need help in removing junk char in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to read the XMl file in text format.

```
Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set TS = FS.OpenTextFile(FilePath, 1, False)
Do While (TS.AtEndOfStream = False)
    s = TS.ReadLine
Loop
```

But while reading i al also getting some junk Char showing Square box even i tried using the Trim but unable to remove this. Please let me know how to remove this char.

Comment: It sounds like you need to replace NewLine characters.

Comment: It is considered polite to accept answers to your questions. You may want to go back and accept some answers to your previous questions. This may motivate further help from other StackOverflow users.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you are reading the file in as text, but since it is in XML format, would it be possible to save the file with a `.xml` extension? This way you could bypass your problem completely, and just read it in using DOM the object created by `CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")`...

---

Another solution (piggybacking off of @Neil's suggestion) may to be check if the character being read in is equal to `vbNewline`, `vbCrLf`, or `vbLf` characters. If they are equal, then simply dont include them in your data pull.